# Who is the legal owner of code in a bitbucket repo?

Tags: ownership

Who is the owner of code uploaded from a personal account to a private Bitbucket repository and there is no license defined in the code, or there is only the name of the author in the header of the code? I suppose that the repository owner can't do anything with the code. While the code author (either mentioned in code header or not) has all the rights for the code.

Comment: I think stackoverflow is not a right place for this question. Take a look at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You mean who holds copyright on the code? I don't think where the code is hosted should matter for that, except you could probably use the history to guess who actually wrote it in the first place. It sounds like there's a more complicated scenario here?

Comment: Based on that there is no any signed contract between the repository owner and the code owner

Comment: There may be some implicit contract e.g. if the repository owner paid the code author, even if there was nothing written down. But this does sound like you need legal advice.

Comment: And in case that there is no paiment? But, suddenly the repository owner revoked the access to the code author?